# Hibernate 4.2.2 create blob from unknown-length input stream

Tags: java, hibernate, stream, blob

Hi i want to create a blob in hibernate from an inputstream, but i don't know the length of the stream.

```
Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(stream, length)
```

how can i crate a blob without knowing the length of the stream?

EDIT1

in older hibernate versions it was possible

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/

Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());

EDIT2

ok but it had an buggy implementation

return new SerializableBlob( new BlobImpl( stream, stream.available() ) );

stream.available isn't the real size

EDIT 3

i tried

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
            LargeObjectManager lobj = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conn).getLargeObjectAPI();
```

but conn is just a NewProxyConnection from c3p0.

Comment: Load it an array, wrap the array with a ByteInputStream and use the array's length for the second argument.

Comment: i just changed it to stream, because i want to handle huge amounts of data without reading it to memeory

Comment: Is it really the best approach for huge amounts of data to be saved in a database as blobs? Isn't much easier and faster to save them to files and then save files paths in the db?

Comment: this is another question ;) ... not mine... but replication speaks for this approach

Comment: You can always save the record using plain Hibernate but leave the blob column NULL and then set the blob column afterwards using low level JDBC. As a workaround should nothing else present itself (which I personally consider to be an actual solution to fit the design, not a workaround). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html

Comment: how can i get org.postgresql.PGConnection within session.doWork? What i get is an NewProxyConnection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what i'm using now

```
Session currentSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(currentSession).createBlob(new byte[0]);
OutputStream setBinaryStream = blob.setBinaryStream(1);
Utils.fastChannelCopy(input, setBinaryStream);
setBinaryStream.close();
```

Comment: What is Utils.fastChannelCopy ?

Comment: just a custom utils function to copy a stream, you can just use ioutils from apache

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the InputStream and a length of -1:

```
session.getLobHelper().createBlob(stream, -1);
```

This works with SQL Server 2008. It seems that Hibernate passes this value directly to the JDBC driver, so this may or may not work depending on your database driver.

Note: If I pass in the incorrect stream length (including 0), I will get a DataException from Hibernate (from the driver: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The stream value is not the specified length. The specified length was 10, the actual length is 13."). With a length of -1, it always works without complaining, and the data is saved successfully to the database.

Comment: HSQL doesn't like that:
` org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Invalid argument in JDBC call: length: -1`

Comment: Since PostgreSQL 9.4 this should work: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html#version_9.4-1200

Comment: Anyone succeeded with Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround could be to save input stream to a file then to read the file into blob.

Comment: This is one of the few answers which makes actually sense

Answer (score 0):

I understand my answer is a little different from your question. But this may help others who land here. For my requirement, i am getting the absolute file path as the input to create a blob. If you too have a similar requirement, you can use the below snippet.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
File file = new File(filePath);
Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
```

file.length() will give you the length of the file.

Comment: This is possible solution,  write the unknown length stream into temp file and use FileInputStream (now of known size)

Answer (score -1):

change the save method in Dao as below

```
@Transactional
public void save(Document document, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    buffer.flush();
    Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(buffer.toByteArray());
    document.setContent(blob);
    session.save(document);
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution, ByteArrayOutputStream buffers all the data in the RAM. I wanted to avoid this

Comment: use byte[] only instead of ByteArrayOutputStream

int expected = inputStream.available();
        byte[] contents = new byte[expected];
        int length = inputStream.read(contents);
         if(length != expected)
            throw new IOException("Could not read full input");

Comment: Not only this reads everything into memory but is overcomplicated

Answer (score -2):

I think, it's a goog solution, if you convert the InputStream to byte array, so you can use the createBlob method, that accepts a byte array instead of an InputStream and the length as parameter. 
For the converting you can use the IOUtils from the Apache Commons IO.

```
Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(IOUtils.toByteArray(stream));
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of streaming :/