# Migrate AbstractLobType to Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.2

Tags: spring, hibernate, jira

I am currently using Hibernate 3 and Spring 3.0. I want to migrate to Hibernate 4 and Spring 3.2. I am using a subclass of `AbstractLobType` to implement a UserType that maps from an `InputStream` to the database (MySQL LONGBLOB):

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobCreator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.AbstractLobType;

public class BlobUserType extends AbstractLobType {

public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.BLOB };
}

public Class returnedClass() {
    return InputStream.class;
}

@Override
protected Object nullSafeGetInternal(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner, LobHandler lobHandler)
throws SQLException, HibernateException {
    return lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, names[0]);
}

@Override
protected void nullSafeSetInternal(PreparedStatement ps, int index, Object value, LobCreator lobCreator)
throws SQLException, HibernateException {
    if (value != null) {
        lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, index, (InputStream) value, -1);
    } else {
        lobCreator.setBlobAsBytes(ps, index, null);
    }
}
}
```

Since `AbstractLobType` is in the `hibernate3`, I should not use it anymore, but what is the alternative?

I did read [this JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9022) on the spring project, but it does not help me at all.

This is the hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="SoundNotification" table="SoundNotification" entity-name="SoundNotificationWithData">
    <id name="m_id" type="int" column="id" unsaved-value="-1">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="m_name" column="name" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="m_data" column="data"
              type="com.mycompany.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.usertype.BlobUserType"
              not-null="true"/>
    <property name="m_size" formula="OCTET_LENGTH(data)"/>
    <property name="m_inUse"
              formula="(select count(1) from EventTypeConfiguration etc where etc.soundNotification=id)"/>
</class>
```

And the Java class:

```
public class SoundNotification extends IntegerEntity
{
    private String m_name;
    private transient InputStream m_data;
    private boolean m_inUse;
    private long m_size;

   // getters and setters ...
}
```

UPDATE with MaterializedBlobType:

My TrafficMap.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="TrafficMapImage" table="TrafficMapImage" entity-name="TrafficMapImageWithData">
    <id name="m_id" column="id" type="int" unsaved-value="-1">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="m_created" column="created" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime"
              not-null="true"/>
    <property name="m_image" column="image"
              type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType"
              not-null="true"/>
    <property name="m_type" column="type" not-null="true">
        <type name="com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.usertype.EnumUserType">
            <param name="enumClass">com.traficon.domain.map.TrafficMapImageType</param>
        </type>
    </property>
</class>
```

The sessionFactory bean in my Spring context:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
            hibernate.show_sql=${hibernate.show_sql}
            hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
            hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true
            hibernate.current_session_context_class=com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.spring.TransactionAwareSessionContext
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>hibernate/authentication.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/SystemPrefs.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/Detector.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/filters.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/EventTypeConfiguration.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/Scenario.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/RunningScenario.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/StorePoint.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/OfflineNetwork.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/Characteristics.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/EventType.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/EventStore.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/IntervalDataMessage.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/IntegrationPeriodConstraints.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/Media.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/TrafficMap.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/CommentLibrary.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/CommentHistory.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>hibernate/Dashboard.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.RollbackReintializerInterceptor"
              scope="prototype"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The logging output:

```
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 13:54:10,525 [main] INFO  hibernate.annotations.common.Version  - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 13:54:10,537 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version  - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.7.Final}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 13:54:10,544 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 13:54:10,545 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - HHH000407: Using java.io streams to persist binary types
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 13:54:10,546 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 13:54:12,302 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

....

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 13 Dec 2013 14:06:12,136 [http-8080-4] INFO  hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  - HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of com.traficon.domain.map.TrafficMapImage.m_image
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Dec 13, 2013 2:06:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mediaServlet threw exception
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.io.InputStream field com.traficon.domain.map.TrafficMapImage.m_image to [B
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:139)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:710)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:379)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4523)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:186)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1108)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:964)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2121)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3941)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:460)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:429)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:206)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:246)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1098)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:175)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2482)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:998)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.HibernateTrafficMapRepository.getTrafficMapImageWithData_aroundBody6(HibernateTrafficMapRepository.java:176)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.HibernateTrafficMapRepository$AjcClosure7.run(HibernateTrafficMapRepository.java:1)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.service.persistence.impl.hibernate.HibernateTrafficMapRepository.getTrafficMapImageWithData(HibernateTrafficMapRepository.java:173)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.getTrafficMapImageWithData(Unknown Source)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at com.traficon.tmsng.server.web.mvc.DownloadTrafficMapImageController.onSubmit(DownloadTrafficMapImageController.java:40)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:272)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:268)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]
```

Comment: And why isn't the JIRA issue helping you? It states that you should use the Hibernate native types (as this is the recommended approach now).

Comment: I don't find any Hibernate native type that uses InputStream. I found `MaterializedBlobType` but that uses `byte[]`

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should use the hibernate provided `MaterializedBlobType` if you want to use `InputStream`s for your Blob then add the following property to you hibernate configuration

```
hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true
```

This will instruct the `MaterializedBlobType` to use an `InputStream` instead of a `byte[]`.

Comment: Does not seem to work. I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.io.InputStream field com.mycompany.domain.map.TrafficMapImage.m_image to [B`

Comment: I added it to the `hibernateProperties` property of my `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`. Is this the good place?

Comment: That should do the trick, unless you have another means of configuring the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

Comment: Since it does not do the trick, is there anything I can check or do to debug this?

Comment: You can enable debug logging for hibernate, that should log what hibernate does while configuring. Can you also add the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` configuration to your question. (and additional hibernate.properties and/or hibernate.cfg.xml.).

Comment: I enabled the logging and it prints: HHH000407: Using java.io streams to persist binary types

Comment: Post your updated hbm file (should have the proper type, add the stack trace you get and also put the logging output).

Comment: I added the requested info.

Comment: Change the type to `materialized_blob` instead of the actual underlying usertype used. Let Hibernate decide (and I assume it does some additional configuration for the type). See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-types

Comment: Sorry, it does not help. I am now using `type="materialized_blob"` in my hbm file, but still the same IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Mea Culpa, I should have read the documentation better, apparently the  `MaterializedBlobType` still expects a `byte[]` as the type regardless what the `hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary` property is. It appears that you cannot do that with the current types of hibernate. There is a normal `BlobType` which works on a `javax.sql.Blob` instance, which you could use the get/set your inputstream. Else creating your own usertype (mimicing what Spring did) is the only way to go I'm afraid. Sorry for all the confusion and time it took (will remove the answer later on!).

Comment: Ok. I will migrate my code to use byte[] instead of InputStream then :(

Comment: Instead of `byte[]` you could also use `javax.sql.Blob` and hide the use of the blob (you can set/get an `InputStream` from that) and you could use the default `BlobType` for that.

Comment: Great! This works fine indeed. Maybe you can remove this answer and put in a better one for me to accept?

Comment: But how do you create a Blob from an InputStream ?

Comment: You can use the `Hibernate` class for that. In JPA you would be able to use a `@PrePersist` to do some saving, not sure how one would do that in plain Hibernate). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908279/hibernate-4-2-2-create-blob-from-unknown-length-input-stream

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own UserType that converts between Blob and InputStream:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class BlobUserType implements UserType
{
// ------------------------ INTERFACE METHODS ------------------------

// --------------------- Interface UserType ---------------------

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes()
    {
        return new int[]{Types.BLOB};
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass()
    {
        return InputStream.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object x, Object y ) throws HibernateException
    {
        boolean result;
        if (x == y)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result = x.equals( y );
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode( Object x ) throws HibernateException
    {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet( ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner ) throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        return rs.getBlob( names[0] ).getBinaryStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet( PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session ) throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        if( value != null )
        {
            InputStream inputStream = (InputStream)value;
            st.setBlob( index, inputStream );
        }
        else
        {
            st.setNull( index, Types.BLOB );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy( Object value ) throws HibernateException
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble( Object value ) throws HibernateException
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble( Serializable cached, Object owner ) throws HibernateException
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace( Object original, Object target, Object owner ) throws HibernateException
    {
        return original;
    }
}
```

Seems to be working fine loading and saving my entity from/to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use AbstractLobType because it is in the hibernate 3 as you said.

You can create your own UserType to convert between Blob and InputStream. However, if you are migrating existing data from Hibernate 3 to 4, your code will not work:

The format of BlobSerializableType has header's information in addition which is something like this:

¬í t{"userServices":[{"accountStatus":"PendingTermsAndConditions","serviceIdentifier":"SNG"}]...}]}

Your code will working (reading, writing) to the format without header:
{"userServices":[{"accountStatus":"PendingTermsAndConditions","serviceIdentifier":"SNG"}]...}]}

My personal solution is to simulate the Hibernate 3 to write and read Blob data as below:

```
package com.newbay.acs.domain.hibernate;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

/**
 * Created by qale0001 on 21/06/2016.
 */
public class CustomMaterializedBlobType implements UserType
{
    private static final int OUTPUT_BYTE_ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE = 1024;

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes()
    {
        return new int[]{Types.BLOB};
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass()
    {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        boolean result;
        if (x == y)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result = x.equals( y );
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob( names[0] );
        InputStream is = blob.getBinaryStream();

        if (is != null) {
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                try {
                    return ois.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    throw new HibernateException("Could not deserialize BLOB contents", ex);
                } finally {
                    ois.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new HibernateException("Could not deserialize BLOB contents", ex);
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if( value != null )
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(OUTPUT_BYTE_ARRAY_INITIAL_SIZE);
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
                try {
                    oos.writeObject(value);
                    oos.flush();
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                    st.setBlob(index, is);
                }
                finally {
                    oos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new HibernateException("Could not serialize BLOB contents", ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            st.setNull( index, Types.BLOB );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

}
```